# How to change Javascript function value with another Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm stuck at another problem with javascript,
my code consists of two parts

**First** a simple dropdown menu:

```
<select>
    <option name="1">1</option>
    <option name="2">2</option>
    <option name="3">3</option>
</select>
```

**Secound** a simple div:

```
<div onClick="doThis('1');">Execute 1</div>
```

My script currently changes the `innerHTML` of the div when a certain option is selected, but now I need it also to change the `onClick` functions value.

Meaning, if I select option **3**, the javascript should look **onClick="doThis('3');**.

I know how to change most of the attributes with javascript, but no idea how I can change a javascript onClick attribute with another javascript function. I googled it, but nothink came up.

So, how can this be done?

All help is apprecianted,
thank you already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use inline javascript events. You're mixing functional code (javascript) and presentation code (HTML) which is an antipattern. If you seperate these concerns properly, the answer becomes somewhat trivial:

HTML:

```
<select id="someSelect">
    <option name="1">1</option>
    <option name="2">2</option>
    <option name="3">3</option>
</select>

<div id="someDiv">Execute</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('someDiv').onclick = function () {
    var select = document.getElementById('someSelect');
    var number = select.value;

    doThis(number);
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jbabey/HzVd7/

Comment: Thanks a lot, works perfect. Was thinking in the wrong direction ;) I was already changing the value like this, dunno why I didn't think of doing the same for `click` option.

Answer (score 0):

*Changing the onClick attribute* is not something you should need to do in most of your JavaScript tasks. Instead, if you know that the `'3'` in your scenario is going to change at some point, then it shouldn't be hard coded into the function call in the first place; make it a variable, or fetch it with a function:

```
<div id="someDiv" onclick="doThis(getValue());">
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use jquery library http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery. And then hang event onsubmit by this way:

```
$('div').click(function(){
  doThis($("select#someSelect").val());
})
```